# How Set token globally in flutter that I can access in whole project

Tags: flutter

I got Token When I call authentication api in my flutter project and I wanted to do is that I can access token with verify api and other all api so what can I do

**How to set token globally to access in whole project**

here is the Example of Token

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJSREUiLCJleHAiOjE2MjQ4OTE0OTEsInN1YiI6ImFzaHdtZWdoIiwicm9sZSI6IkNsaWVudCIsImF1ZCI6IlJERSIsInB3ZGNoIjpmYWxzZSwiaXAiOiIyMjMuMjI2LjIyMy4xODYifQ.mZ1jUM3t0gqYAQKTkHXqJ_sGy7m2FBeF4P7cCmBvuWA"}
```

Comment: You could use shared preferences for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Shared preferences plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to store and retrieve the authentication token.

```
  void storeToken(String token) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('token', token);
  }
```

To retrieve it, you can do -

```
String token = prefs.getString('token');
```